# Using Web Service to authenticate on LDAP

Tags: web-services, blackberry, ldap, connection

Since it' apparently not possible to authenticate with LDAP on my BlackBerry App, I'm trying to use a kind of workaround. Instead of authenticate directly on the LDAP Server, I want to use a Web Service in between. So it looks like this

```
App --calls--> Web Service --calls--> LDAP Server
```

So the Web Service should take the username and password given from the Application and send it to the LDAP Server. If its possible to sign in, the Web Service gets a TRUE as response and forward it to the App.

That's how it should work. But at the moment, when I call the Web Service from the App, I get following error:

> `SoapFault - faultcode: 'S:Server' faultstring:
>   'java.lang.NullPointerException' faultactor: 'null' detail:
>   org.kxml2.kdom.Node@21e05a11`

Seems like a Server problem but I don't know where :(
Well, that's the Web Service I'm using:

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;  
import javax.jws.WebService;  

import com.novell.ldap.LDAPConnection;  
import com.novell.ldap.LDAPException;  

@Stateless  
@WebService()  
public class ldapServiceBean implements ldapService {

    @Override
    public String error() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean ldapLogin(String username, String password) {
         int ldapPort = LDAPConnection.DEFAULT_PORT;
         int ldapVersion = LDAPConnection.LDAP_V3;
         String ldapHost = "dc1.somehost ";
         String loginDN =
         "CN="+username+",OU=employee,OU=user,DC=somehost";

         byte[] passwordBytes = password.getBytes();
         LDAPConnection lc = new LDAPConnection();

         try {
             // connect to the server
             lc.connect( ldapHost, ldapPort );

             // authenticate to the server
             lc.bind( ldapVersion, loginDN, passwordBytes );
             System.out.println("Bind successful");

             return true;
         }
         catch( LDAPException e ) {
             if ( e.getResultCode() == LDAPException.NO_SUCH_OBJECT ) {
                 System.err.println( "Error: No such entry" );
             } else if ( e.getResultCode() ==
                 LDAPException.NO_SUCH_ATTRIBUTE ) {
                 System.err.println( "Error: No such attribute" );
             } else {
                 System.err.println( "Error: " + e.toString() );
             }
         }
        return false;
    }
```

And that's the method calling the Web Service

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "";  
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "ldapLogin";  
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://ldapproxy.somehost/";  
    private static final String URL = "http://myIP:8080/LDAPProxy/ldapServiceBeanService";  

...  


public boolean login(String username, String password) {


        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 

        //SoapObject
        request.addProperty("username", username);
        request.addProperty("password", password);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        //envelope.dotNet = true;
        //envelope.bodyOut = request;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);       

        HttpTransport httpTransport = new HttpTransport(URL);
        try
        {

            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            System.out.println("request: " + httpTransport.requestDump);
            resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

            return true;

        }catch(SoapFault sF){
            String error = sF.toString();
            Dialog.alert(error);
        }
        catch (Exception aE)
        {
            Dialog.alert("Connection failed");
            aE.printStackTrace ();
        }
        return false;

    }
```

---

What I found out so far:
It seems that the webservice don't receives the username and password property. As I print them I get:

```
`CN=null, OU=employee, OU=...`
```

Like I've read at this post [Web service recieves null parameters from application using ksoap method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046489/web-service-recieves-null-parameters-from-application-using-ksoap-method) it seems ksoap have a problem with colons. I changed my NAMESPACE but without any success. Maybe I need to change my URL too. But how would I do this while I still need to use localhost ?

Answer (score 1):

As always when doing LDAP bind testing this way, recall that the standard requires that a bind of a username, no password, is a successful Anonymous bind, so therefore you MUST validate for this case (empty password) on login attempts.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried an anonymous bind manually, but I get an error again. In this case, it's not possible (and allowed) to login without password.